# How to add and remove object with time limit in array or list - unity 5 c#.?

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, unity-game-engine

I want to add and remove prefabs dynamically to to array with time limit. When User click button prefabs will be instantiate for 5 seconds. After five seconds this prefabs should automatically destroy.

If user try to Instantiate a new prefabs before 5 seconds then they can.

If first prefabs instantiate with 5 seconds life time and second prefabs will instantiate at 3 seconds of first then second prefabs should destroy after total 7 seconds.

Anyone can help me with little code. I use coroutine but I can't do this.

```
    float pLife = 5.0f;
    private IEnumerator SetParticleLifeTime(float time){

    while (pLife - Time.time) {         

        Debug.Log (time-Time.time);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
    };
    Destroy (this.gameObject);

}
```

I don't know How to add prefabs to array and remove it. Anyone can help me.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply call `Destroy(GameObject, float)` on the prefab you instantiate.

See the [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) for further reference on that.

```
var yourGameObject = Instantiate(yourPrefab) as GameObject;
Destroy(yourGameObject, 5); // Destroys 'yourGameObject' after 5 seconds
```

Comment: That is awesome to know, I always end up making timer functions to handle this sort of thing.